# <div> inside another <div> same percentage but inner overlaps?

Tags: html, css

I've got a `div` within a `div`, both are percentage based for the page but the nested `div` overlaps slightly to the right.

I'm actually trying to get the white box sit inside the first light blue `div` with a small `margin` on all sides so you can see a bit of the darker backround color, making it stand out more.

Editing to point out that the point of the `position:fixed` is to make the white box move as you scroll.

A solution was posted that involved chaning the `position` to `relative`, although this obviously stops the box from moving.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shiroslullaby/omuL7fxk/)

[image]

```css
div {
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#header {
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #F38630;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.left {
    height: 1300px;
 width: 25%;
 background-color: #A7DBD8;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.right {
 height: 1300px;
 width: 75%;
 background-color: #E0E4CC;
 float: right;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#footer {
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #69D2E7;
 clear: both;
}

#fixedleft {
    height: 50px;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: fixed;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Result</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div class="left"><div id="fixedleft"></div></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would use `#fixedleft {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;

}` but maybe the position:fixed is useful at some other point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your margin is increasing with the width.

Try:

```
#fixedleft {
    height: 50px;
    width: calc(25% - 2px);
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

Comment: calc(25% - 6px)  
seems to be pretty good
Did not know about this thx for posting!

Comment: @Shiroslullaby Alternately, use `box-sizing: border-box;` which is more compatible with older browsers and probably faster. You can get the other prefixed versions from css3please.com

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this issue is due to default `body` `margin` as it doesn't affect the `width` of your `fixed` `div`(as you can see in the example, it's `width` is always the same, no matter what `margin` value you set, unlike it's container's `width`) :

```
body { margin:0; }
```

There is still a problem with the inner `margin` (`1px`) that pushes it out of the container, you can use `calc` for it, here is an example:

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/807tpm0m/2/)

Comment: Someone else mentioned Calc (which I did not know about) and Im looking into it thx for the body margin:0 suggestion and appreciate the JSFiddle!

Answer (score 0):

```
#fixedleft {
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 50px;
margin: 2px;
position: relative;
width: 98%;
}
```

Please try this instear of

```
#fixedleft {
height: 50px;
width: 25%;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
position: fixed;
margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;

}
```

Comment: This does what I want as far as positioning of the white box inside the darker blue background.  
Is there any way to get a div position to move when the screen is scrolled other than the postion: fixed attribute?  
Im wanting to get this appearance with the ability for the box to move as the screen does.

Answer (score 0):

if you load jQuery..

```
$(window).bind("resize", function(){
    $("#fixedleft").width( parseInt($(".left").width()) -2)
})
$(function(){$(window).resize()})
```